# Explicit degeneracy in SPT phases

Tags: symmetry, topological-order, quantum-hall-effect

In the wikipedia article on [symmetry protected topological phases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_protected_topological_order)
the author states:

> If the boundary is a gapped degenerate state, the degeneracy may be caused by spontaneous symmetry breaking and/or (intrinsic) topological order.

I am wondering why the degeneracy cannot be caused by an explicit symmetry. 
Say, in the case of time-reversal symmetry, why can't we have a Kramers degenerate 
ground state?

As a specific example: The K-Matrix of a "non-fractionalized" Topological Insulator reads $K=\mathrm{diag}(1,-1)$. The ground state
degeneracy is given by $\lvert \det(K)\rvert=1$. Is this consistent with Kramers' theorem stating that the ground state should be at least two-fold degenerate?

Comment: **the degeneracy caused by an explicit symmetry** is a special case of **the degeneracy caused by spontaneous symmetry breaking**.

Comment: Okay. So one can define the term symmetry breaking in terms of the generators of symmetry commuting with the Hamiltonian and the ground state subspace transforming under some representation of the symmetry group. In the case of explicit symmetry breaking the representation happens to be the singlet representation. In the case of spontaneous symmetry breaking the representation happens to be higher dimensional. This makes sense. Does the formula |det(K)| for the GS degeneracy only refer to the topological degeneracy?

Comment: Yes, |det(K)| only refer to the topological degeneracy. Also In the case of explicit symmetry breaking,  the degenerate eigenstates do not form a representation, in particular they do not form a singlet representation.

Comment: |det(K)| refer to the topological degeneracy on a torus. It has noting to do with the degeneracy on the boundary.